# MySQL connection error PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This may seem redundant, but I browsed through many varieties of this question and nothing really helps.

I have a domain www.test.co.za

I want to connect a MySQL database using php's mysql_connect method.

```
mysql_connect("test.co.za","test_user","u$er23");
```

when I run the query I get this error.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'test_user'@'server' (using password: YES) in PATH on line __
```

I called for support from the Web Host and I've not seen any changes because they just put me on hold for long periods of time.

This is on a shared domain, and the user `test_user` was created, the password is correct, the server name... I don't know if it is correct.

Please help me, I'm so frustrated. Thank you

Comment: Contact them or look in their help documents. You might need to use localhost instead of test.co.za for the host.

Comment: Does the user have the correct permissions to the db? Also mysql_ functions have been deprecated, look into MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: Also probably shouldn't post the actual connection info

Comment: Sorry for down vote, but I don't think anyone will find this question useful after using keywords like "MySQL connection error"

Answer (score 4):

When you have a dollar sign in a string, use single quote(like in your MySql password):

```
mysql_connect("test.co.za","test_user",'u$er23');
```

And have in mind that **mysql_*** functions are deprecated!

Comment: *Ohhhhhhh* right. The dollar sign in double quotes is looking for the variable `er23`.

Comment: Change the password too if it was likewise (to something less obvious).